# move a django model to another app which is parent model for another model

Tags: python, django, refactoring, django-migrations

I have to django models in two diffrent apps like app1 and app2, in app1 I got Model1 and in app2 I got BaseModel and the Model1 is like this

```
class Model1(BaseModel):
...
```

Model1 and BaseModel where in one app but I moved Model1 to app2 and now I want to move BaseModel to app2 too.
My problem is when I try to move BaseModel to app2 I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'app1.model1'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

What I do is simple:

1. I write migration for renaming table of BaseModel to app2_basemodel then I write migration for creating model in app2
2. I create migration for altering field basemodel_ptr which is used for inheritance
3. i move the BaseModel code to app2 and delete BaseModel with a migration from app1

This method worked for moving Model1 but when I try to move this base Model I get this error.

I appreciate any helps including any other way to reach this refactor idea of moving BaseModel to app1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django does not come with a builtin migration operation for that, but you can achieve this by piecing together multiple migration operations.

Migrations not only change the database, but they also keep a state of all model. You have to make sure to keep the state in sync with the database which complicates things a bit. The key is using [`migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#separatedatabaseandstate).

Assuming you have these model definitions:

```
# app1/models.py
from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    base_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

# app2/models.py
from django.db import models
from app1.models import BaseModel

class Model1(BaseModel):
    model_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And you want to migrate to this:

```
# app1/models.py empty
# app2/models.py

from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    base_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Model1(BaseModel):
    model_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

You have to create three migrations:

- In App1: rename the table of `app1.BaseModel` from `app1_basemodel` to `app2_basemodel`. This also takes care of adjusting the foreign-key constraint on the `basemodel_ptr` column.
- In App2: add `app2.BaseModel` and re-create `app2.Model1` with `app2.BaseModel` as basemodel. These changes are only done to the *migration state* and do not touch the database!
- In App1: remove `app1.BaseModel` from the migration state. Again, no DB changes.

Here is how that looks in code:

```
# app1/migrations/0002_rename_basemodel_table.py
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    atomic = False
    dependencies = [
        ('app1', '0001_initial'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelTable(
            name='BaseModel',
            table='app2_basemodel'
        ),
    ]

# app2/migrations/0002_change_basemodel.py
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app2', '0001_initial'),
        ('app1', '0002_rename_basemodel_table')
    ]

    state_operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BaseModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('base_field', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Model1',
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Model1',
            fields=[
                ('basemodel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='app2.BaseModel')),
            ],
            bases=('app2.basemodel',),
        ),
    ]
    database_operations = [
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
            database_operations,
            state_operations
        )
    ]

# app1/0003_remove_basemodel.py
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app1', '0002_rename_basemodel_table'),
        ('app2', '0002_change_basemodel')
    ]

    state_operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='BaseModel',
        ),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
            database_operations=None,
            state_operations=state_operations
        )
    ]
```

Obviously, you have to adjust these migrations to reflect your actual models.
I'm afraid that if you have other models with relations to `Model1` this might become even more complicated.

**Disclaimer:** I've tested these with SQLite and PostgreSQL, but use it at your own risk! Make sure you have a backup before you run it on production data.

Before:

```
$ python manage.py dbshell
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-27 16:48:08
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "app1_basemodel" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "base_field" varchar(64) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "app2_model1" ("basemodel_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "app1_basemodel" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "model_field" varchar(64) NOT NULL);
...

$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug 22 2018, 15:22:33)
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from app2.models import Model1
>>> Model1.__bases__
(<class 'app1.models.BaseModel'>,)
>>> Model1.objects.create(base_field='a', model_field='A')
<Model1: Model1 object (1)>
>>> Model1.objects.create(base_field='b', model_field='B')
<Model1: Model1 object (2)>
>>>
```

After:

```
sqlite> .schema
...
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "app2_basemodel" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "base_field" varchar(64) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "app2_model1" ("basemodel_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "app2_basemodel" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "model_field" varchar(64) NOT NULL);
...

>>> from app2.models import Model1
>>> Model1.__bases__
(<class 'app2.models.BaseModel'>,)
>>> for obj in Model1.objects.all():
...  print(obj.base_field, obj.model_field)
...
a A
b B
```

Alternatively, you could look into [writing a custom migration operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own).

Comment: Hi, I was thinking about removing app1 from State and recreating it and it worked! I was looking to write my answer on stack overflow and you just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to removing model1 from the state and it worked
Here is what I did to get it working(some names are changed from what I wrote in question):

1. removing model1 from the state

   ```
   state_operations = [migrations.DeleteModel('Model')]
   operations =[migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(state_operations=state_operations)]
   ```
2. renaming table for the BaseModel(you need to set atomic=True for SQLite)

   ```
   operations = [
   migrations.AlterModelTable(
       name='basemodel',
       table='first_basemodel',
   ),
   ```

   ]
3. moving Model to first app

   ```
   def update_contentypes(apps, schema_editor):
       ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')
       db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

       qs = ContentType.objects.using(db_alias).filter(app_label='second', model='basemodel')
       qs.update(app_label='first')


   def update_contentypes_reverse(apps, schema_editor):
       ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')
       db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

       qs = ContentType.objects.using(db_alias).filter(app_label='first', model='basemodel')
       qs.update(app_label='second')

   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

   dependencies = [
       ('first', '0002_delete_model_from_state'),
       ('second', '0002_auto_20181218_0717')
   ]
   state_operenterations = [
           migrations.CreateModel(
               name='BaseModel',
               fields=[
                   ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                   ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
               ],
           ),
       ]

   database_operations = [
       migrations.RunPython(update_contentypes, update_contentypes_reverse),
   ]

   operations = [
       migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
           state_operations=state_operations,
           database_operations=database_operations
       ),
   ]
   ```
4. deleting BaseModel in app2 from the state

   ```
   state_operations = [
   migrations.DeleteModel('BaseModel'),
   ]

   operations = [
   migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(state_operations=state_operations)
   ]
   ```
5. moving the code and adding back the Model1

   ```
   state_operations = [migrations.CreateModel(
   name='Model',
   fields=[
   ('basemodel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='first.BaseModel')),
       ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
   ],
   bases=('first.basemodel',),),]

   operations = [migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(state_operations=state_operations)]
   ```

This solution worked for me without any data loss tested on SQLite and PSQL.